# Exhaustive Random Neural Architecture Search

Tags: pytorch

I am looking for an AutoML system that exhaustively tries all the possible combinations of neural architectures that PyTorch can support (in terms of [predefined layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html)). Would anyone know if such a library/piece of code exists? The current AutoML libraries I can find seem to just try a combination of popular architectures.

The only library I have found that is similar is [HungaBunga](https://github.com/ypeleg/HungaBunga) for scikit-learn.

Comment: Usually when experimenting with different hyper-parameters I just iteratively train different models and compare their results. Not sure if there is a library that does this automatically in pytorch.